# Prove the following by using mathematical induction

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

If we define the alphabet such that $$ \Sigma = {\{a,b}\}  $$ and let $w$ be a string over it. I'd like to prove

$$ ( \operatorname{comp}(w))^R = \operatorname{comp}(w^R) $$

where $$ w^R$$ and $$\operatorname{comp}(w) $$ 
are reverse of $w$ and complement of $w$ that can be obtained by changing all $a$’s to
$b$’s and all $b$’s to $a$’s in w.
For example, if $w$ is $abaaabb$ , $\operatorname{comp}(w)$ is $babbbaa$ and $$w^R$$ is $bbaaaba$.

Comment: What have you been able to do so far?

Comment: Well I tried to do the following: Let x be a string and let x rev be “ the same” string but backwards.I proved that $$(xy)^R =  y^R x^R $$ for
arbitrary strings x, y over an alphabet Σ

Comment: You noted in your title that this is a proof by induction. Have you setup and proved the base case? Are you able to setup the inductive step?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to start

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Nope. Its a question for preparation to exam

Comment: The induction variable in this case is the length of the string.

Comment: If you don't know how to start, start with the base case.  What would the base case of the induction be?

Comment: Emnet said that it would be the length of the string

Comment: The length of $w$ is the *variable* on which you do the induction. So, what would be a *base* for your induction? What would the initial value of the variable be?

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove the result by induction on the length $|w|$ of $w$. If $|w| = 0$, then $w$ is the empty word and the result is trivially true. Suppose that the result holds for all words of length $\leqslant n$ and let $w$ be a word of length $n + 1$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that the last letter of $w$ is an $a$. Thus $w = va$ for some word $v$ such that $|v| = n$. Then $w^R = av^R$ and by the induction hypothesis applied to $v$, we have 
$$
(\operatorname{comp}(v))^R = \operatorname{comp}(v^R).
$$
Now, observing that $\operatorname{comp}(va) = \operatorname{comp}(v)b$ and $\operatorname{comp}(av^R) = b\operatorname{comp}(v^R)$, we get
\begin{align}
 (\operatorname{comp}(w))^R &= ( \operatorname{comp}(va))^R = ( \operatorname{comp}(v)b)^R = b(\operatorname{comp}(v))^R\\ 
&= b\operatorname{comp}(v^R) = \operatorname{comp}(av^R) = \operatorname{comp}(w^R)
\end{align}
which concludes the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

This fact is absolutely obvious, and the intended induction proof is apt to make it less believable. Hear this:

We are given a finite $\{a,b\}$-string. Interchanging all $a$s and $b$s, and then reversing it produces the same result as first reversing it and then interchanging all $a$s and $b$s.